# How to show/hide divs with multiple select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been sorting a HTML5 form with jQuery to show/hide divs based on the selected value in the select menu. However I've come across a problem where if an option is selected, then it is changed, the original selection with its div is not hidden, and the new one is added to the page, and generating more than one select menu if an user changes their choice in the select menu. I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes would help and point out the solution to this, as I would like the divs to show/hide based on the value or if it's not selected at all.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="country">
  <h1>Pick country</h1>
  <select class="country_option">
    <option value="england">England</option>
    <option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="not-selected">
  <p>Please select a country to be able to pick the region.</p>
</div>

<div class="england" id="england">
  <h3>Pick region in England</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
    <option value="East">East</option>
    <option value="West">West</option>
    <option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="scotland" id="scotland">
  <h3>Pick region in Scotland</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="ireland" id="ireland">
  <h3>Pick region in Ireland</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="Northern">Northern</option>
    <option value="Republic">Republic</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wales" id="wales">
  <h3>Pick region in Wales</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.england, .scotland, .ireland, .wales').hide();

  $('.country_option').change(function() {
  $('.not-selected').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Alternatively, here is the [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/j_mes/pen/rcdxJ). I look forward to anyone pointing the obvious or the less obvious solution to my conundrum at the moment.

Comment: I wrote FieldState (http://mitya.co.uk/fieldState) for just this sort of scenario - avoiding messy DOM-logic. Here's a Codepen with it used for your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHKgr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually included any code within your change function which will hide the divs. I guess that the intention of `$('.not-selected').hide();`was to do this but you never apply the .not-selected class to any of the country divs.

Perhaps a simple method would be to call the hide() function on all the country divs every time a change is made.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  $('.country_option').change(function() {
    $('.england, .scotland, .ireland, .wales').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: I really like how you have answered my question, you've pointed out where I went wrong and provided the solution to this instead of bombarding with code and not really explaining anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be looks like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('.england, .scotland, .ireland, .wales').hide();
  $('.country_option').change(function() {
    $('.england, .scotland, .ireland, .wales').hide();
  $('.not-selected').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="country">
  <h1>Pick country</h1>
  <select class="country_option">
    <option value="england">England</option>
    <option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="not-selected">
  <p>Please select a country to be able to pick the region.</p>
</div>

<div class="england" id="england">
  <h3>Pick region in England</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
    <option value="East">East</option>
    <option value="West">West</option>
    <option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="scotland" id="scotland">
  <h3>Pick region in Scotland</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="ireland" id="ireland">
  <h3>Pick region in Ireland</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="Northern">Northern</option>
    <option value="Republic">Republic</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="wales" id="wales">
  <h3>Pick region in Wales</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>
```