# Show/Hide toggle not working with select name for database output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This was originally pointed out and [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992935/how-to-show-hide-divs-with-multiple-select-options) this morning, but then I had to add `name="region_option"` to the select element so that it would output the value into a SQL query. The database/query stuff is all good, however I could not get the Show/Hide to work properly with the regions once again. I'm stuck at getting it to work with the `select` having the `name="region_option"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bodytype">
  <h2>Bodytype</h2>
  <input class="bodytype--owls" name="bodytype_option" type="radio" value="owls">Owls</input>
  <input class="bodytype--others" name="bodytype_option" type="radio" value="others">Others</input>
</div>

<div class="country">
  <h2>Pick country</h2>
  <select name="country_option">
    <option value="not-selected">Select the country</option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="not-selected">
  <h2>Notice!</h2>
  <p>Please select a country to be able to pick the region.</p>
</div>

<div class="regions" id="England">
  <h3>Pick region in England</h3>
  <select name="region_option">
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
    <option value="East">East</option>
    <option value="West">West</option>
    <option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="regions" id="Scotland">
  <h3>Pick region in Scotland</h3>
  <select name="region_option">
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="regions" id="Ireland">
  <h3>Pick region in Ireland</h3>
  <select name="region_option">
    <option value="Northern">Northern</option>
    <option value="Republic">Republic</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="regions" id="Wales">
  <h3>Pick region in Wales</h3>
  <select name="region_option">
    <option value="North">North</option>
    <option value="South">South</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button class="identify__button">Identify</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#England, #Scotland, #Ireland, #Wales').hide();

  $('.country_option').change(function() {
  $('.not-selected, #England, #Scotland, #Ireland, #Wales').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

I would love to know what I'm missing to fix this, and why did it not work in the first place. I have taken the liberty to put it in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/j_mes/pen/rcdxJ) for ease of convenience.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a selector for `class=country_option` when it is actually `name=country_option`.

try

```
$('[name="country_option"]').change(function() {
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mvt0982x/

Or better yet (to be more obvious):

```
$('select[name="country_option"]').change(function() {
```

Comment: That solved it. It always helps to have a second pair of eyes on this I guess. Thank you very much!